# Is this the right "workflow" when working with GIT?

Tags: git, github, command-line

I'm new to GIT and I'm  trying to understand if this is a logical order to do things as projects get started.

This is in situations where I would work on an existing project:

1. `git clone` to clone the existing repository to my local pc.
2. `git branch` so I can work on my edits in a separate branch.
3. work on my code and make changes.

(Question:  does order matter here?  do I have to `git branch` before I start typing changes, or does it matter?)

4. As I work though my code, if I want to make sure I have the most updated work from other peeps, I can git pull.

(Question:  Is there any concern with `Git pull` pulling down changes to only that single branch?)

5. Continue making changes
6. `git add, git commit, git push`
7. does `git push` automatically merge my changes with the master, or is that another command?

Is there anything else I need to do (whether it's cleanup, etc etc).  Not sure what else is needed since I"m super new to it.

Comment: You can create the branch after you've started to change the files. You *should* create and checkout the branch *before* you commit your first commit "on that branch" though, or there will be more work to adjust the branches to be correct.

Comment: git push does not in any way merge anything to anything. It pushes your branch, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

> Question: does order matter here? do I have to git branch before I start typing changes, or does it matter?

You can change files before make a branch. It just create **the branch** from the current HEAD, copy all uncommited changes and sets the HEAD there

`git checkout -b <branch_name>`

[checkout documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout)

> Question: Is there any concern with Git pull pulling down changes to only that single branch?

First of all, make sure you are in a branch that you **don't want to pull**. For example, if you have *master* and *develop* branch, you are trying to pull the *develop branch* then stay in master branch.

```
git checkout master
git pull origin develop
```

[pull documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull)

> 7. does `git push` automatically merge my changes with the master, or is that another command?

`git push` doesn‘t merge your changes with the master. It will push a new branch to your repository, but only `git push` doesn’t work, you must take this command: `git push -u origin <branch_name>`

To merge your branch with the master, you must `merge` your branch in `master`:

```
git checkout master
git merge <branch_name>
```

[branch and merge documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging)